# How to display the encoding of a floating-point value

Tags: c, math, floating-point, formatting

How can we print the encoding of a floating-point value in C?
I know I can use `%A`, but that isn't the format I want.

For example, if my value is 1.3416407, I want to print ”0x3FABBAE2“, I do not “0X1.5775C4P+0”.

Comment: I applaud you wanting `0x` as the prefix and upper-case A-F for the hex digits.  Be aware that the standard doesn't make that easy; you have to code the format explicitly (`"0x%.8X"`, for example).  If you use `%X`, you get 0X as the prefix but A-F for the digits; if you use `%x`, you get 0x as the prefix but a-f for the digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a union, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union {
    float f;
    uint32_t i;
} u;

u.f = 1.3416407f;
printf("%#X\n", u.i);
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I COULDN'T FIND THIS ANYWHERE!

Comment: not that it matters, but I think the max number of digits in a floating point is `6`. +1 for using a 32-bit integer instead of `int`

Comment: @Taylor Flores, 6 is likely from FLT_DIG "number of decimal digits, q, such that any floating-point number with q decimal digits can be rounded into a floating-point number with p radix b digits and back again without change to the q decimal digits,".  So if you are round-tripping, 6 is OK.  If you want "max number of digits" it needs a more precise definition.  You would need to do a "%.7e" to printf() all floats distinctly.

Answer (score 2):

The union idea present by @Paul R is good but would benefit with refinements

```
union {
    float f;
    uint32_t i;
} u;

u.f = 1.3416407f;
printf("0x%08" PRIX32 "\n", u.i);
```

This insures 8 hexadecimal characters are printed, zero padding as needed.  It also matches the sizeof(u.i) should it differ from sizeof(int).

Though it does suffer should from the uncommon sizeof(float) != sizeof(uint32_t);

Answer (score 1):

You can walk the type octet by octet:

```
float f = 1.3416407;
unsigned char *fp = (void *)&f;
size_t i;
printf("0x");
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(float); ++i) {
    printf("%02X", fp[i]);
}
puts("");
```

You may need to print the octets in reverse order depending on the desired endianess.

Comment: Not my down-vote, but maybe the `i[(uint8_t *)&fl]` notation is a factor.

Comment: Hmmm, this appears to fail due to [anti-aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/2410359).

Comment: Is that because of  C11 §6.5 7?

Comment: @chux: Yes, the last bullet point is the exemption for `char` types.

Answer (score 1):

To print the hexadecimal presentation of an arbitrary thing, use

```
union {
    arbitrary object;
    unsigned char bytes[sizeof (arbitrary)];
} u;
```

I.e.

```
union {
    float object;
    unsigned char bytes[sizeof (float)];
} u;

u.object = 1.3416407f;
printf("0x");
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(u.bytes); i++) {
    printf("%02hhx", u.bytes[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Or to reverse the bytes for little endian:

```
printf("0x");
for (size_t i = sizeof(u.bytes) - 1; i < sizeof(u.bytes); i--) {
    printf("%02hhx", u.bytes[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

The code above assumes that `CHAR_BIT == 8`.

Comment: @chux good point :D I was staring at the output and since it looked OK I didn't notice that I didn't specify the width.

Comment: For the pedantic: Something like `printf("%0*hhx", (CHAR_BIT+3)/4, u.bytes[i]);`  Still this answer good enough as `CHAR_BIT == 8` is _very_ common .